# Concurrency memory corruption using Boost 1.55 Thread and Filesystem (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency, filesystems

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include "boost/thread/thread.hpp"

using namespace std;

void testEx(std::string & name){
    while (1){
        boost::filesystem::path perc(name);
        if (boost::filesystem::exists(perc))
            cout << "yes" << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::string name = "c:\\text.txt";
    vector<boost::thread> pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
        pool.emplace_back(testEx, name);

    while (1){
        std::ofstream out(name, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
        out << "a" << std::endl;
        out.close();
    }
    for (auto & t : pool)
        t.join();
}
```

The main thread is writing a file. With child threads i check if the file exists. The program often crashes with memory corruption in the line where i create a boost::filesystem::path instance.

If i use std::thread instead of boost::thread the program works fine.

Is there anything i can do to get this program work with boost::thread (lots of legacy code). Why is this happening?

Comment: could it be that it's actually failing because you use iostreams (e.g. `std::cout`) unsynchronized? Try a mutex around all output stream, or try running without any actual console output.

Answer (score 0):

By now i resolved by linking dynamically boost::filesystem too

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK
```

just a workaround  anyway